# Mercurial file protocol

Tags: http, file, mercurial, protocols, bitbucket

does Mercurial have an HTTP protocol we could browse files/folders/branches instead of clone/pull changesets?

I've seen something using TortoiseHG WebServer and access http://localhost:8080/ using browser but completely different HTML is served when you use project on https://bitbucket.org/ (at least I could not find the same representation).

**Update** the [HttpCommandProtocol](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HttpCommandProtocol) document describes only changesets but not files/folders. So, the task is to download only few files only for particular revision (for example with tip 'stable') and a list of files. However I do not want to download a complete repository for this.

Non HTTP protocols are welcome but conditions are the same: do not download a complete repository.

**Update 2** hgweb serves static HTML and files. Is it always the same HTML fromat for different hgweb versions? What about bitbucket.org? Is there any common protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed already, the HttpCommandProtocol defines the exchange of repository information and changesets - it ensures that you can clone/push/pull from/to any repo served by HTTP. But AFAIK there's no standard for how to browse a repo (e.g. getting a single file of a certain revision).

You'll have to adapt to whatever URL scheme your hosting system of choice uses (as you also noticed, *hgweb* and *bitbucket* have different schemes). Depending on your use case you could define your own file access protocol and feed it to an converter.

For instance you might want to access files with this scheme:

```
<repo-url>/<rev>/<path>
```

Where `<repo-url>` is the URL you use to clone/push/pull. In practice you would then use URLs like that:

```
https://bitbucket.org/user/repo/<rev>/<path>
https://hgwebhost.org/.../repo/<rev>/<path>
```

Obviously these are virtual URLs which do not exist. That's where your converter comes in: check the hosting system type and convert URLs accordingly:

```
https://bitbucket.org/user/repo/raw/<rev>/<path>
https://hgwebhost.org/.../repo/raw-file/<rev>/<path>
```

If your converter knows *bitbucket* and *hgweb*, then it already works with a good deal of repositories out there.

Comment: Do you know any documentation on hgweb and bitbucket static HTMLs? What about other hostings code.google, assembla, SF, etc?

Comment: What information are you looking for in the documentation? Can't you just browse some example projects on different hosting sites and check which URL pattern they use?

Comment: I mean documentation about format of serviced HTML pages. I'm more interested in client side. For example, a program that browse remote Mercurial Repositories and generates a report without downloading complete repositories.

Comment: You want to analyze HTML pages to guess the serving system (*hgweb*, ...) and then the corresponding URL pattern? I'd expect URL patterns to be stable, but I don't think this is true for the format of the actual HTML pages (there's no good reason). I would guess URL patterns based on domain names (yes, you'll have to maintain a list) and fall back to *hgweb* URL patterns for unknown domains. Without knowing what you actually want to do, it is hard to make better suggestions.

Comment: @Oben. Thank you. You are right. I would like analyse HTML for the list of files because it looks like there is no other way to get this information without downloading complete repo. Yes, for different repo hosting it will be different way to analyse HTML (by default hgweb). I just thought there is some better more robust solution. :-(

Comment: If you want to analyze the code anyway, the robust solution is to clone the repo and deal purely with the code instead of having to deal with an intermediary html layer.

Comment: I agree with @jamessan. You could keep the last used *n* repos in a cache, so you don't need to clone that often, just update them before accessing files in them. Of course this requires `hg` to be installed on the downloading system -- as I commented before, knowing what application you actually are working on could be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial has hgweb.  It can be deployed via any wsgi container and I think it even has CGI support.

Comment: As far as I understood from [HttpCommandProtocol](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HttpCommandProtocol), it serves mostly changesets. But what about files and folders?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding.  hgweb is a full http-based Mercurial server and repository browser.  This is *the* way to create an http-based mercurial server.

Comment: I think hgweb is what I see on my localhost when I run TortoiseHg WebServer. However, does the same server/protocol run on bitbuket.org? As I said before, it looks like bitbucket.org serves completely different HTML. Does it mean that hgweb is not a part of standard mercurial protocol?

Comment: HGweb is part of the Mercurial package, it can stand-alone, or as a CGI script under another webserver (Apache for instance) to serve multiple repositories. Bitbucket has written it's own webserver on top of Mercurial, that also includes wiki, issue tracking, download features.

Comment: Thank you, @Ton. So, it means there is no common protocol for browsing files?

Answer (score 2):

If you just go to any hg repo and type

```
hg serve
```

you will have a webserver listening at a url that you can point a browser at. The formatting of the webpages generated by hg can be changed via templates. It is very likely bitbucket.org has their own fancier templates, hence they have a prettier webpages.

Further the listening url can be used to push and pull from as well using hg. This is in fact the same website that is channeled via hgweb.cgi and also the underlying mechanism for doing push/pull over SSH.

Comment: Do you know where I could find documentation or source code for these templates?

Comment: That depends on how hg is installed on your system. On my system the folder `/usr/share/mercurial/templates` has them. There is a directory per template. Further, if you look at the documentation for hgweb.cgi you can see how to configure it to chose any particular template.